# Definition of the spectrum of a ring, $\operatorname{Spec}A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative unital ring. $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is defined to be the collection of all ring 0 homomorphisms from $A$ to some field $K$, where we identify $f:A\to K$ with $g:A\to K'$ if there exists a map $\varphi:K\to K'$ such that $g=f\circ \varphi$.

My question is : Should the map $\varphi$ be bijective? If we don't assume that $\varphi$ is bijective, how to check that $f\sim g$ implies $g\sim f$?

Comment: You don't need to check anything. I would interpret that definition as saying the maps are identified if there is a map in at least one direction.

Comment: But if it is an equivalence class, it should be symmetric.

Comment: I think it should be $g=\varphi \circ f$. Also, this relation as stated here is not symmetric and that's ok (it's an abuse of notation if you want). You can define $\sim$ as the smallest equivalent relation in which $f\sim g$ when $g=\varphi\circ f$. If you are not comfortable with that, you can define $\sim$ as follows: $f\sim g$ iff there is a field $L$ and morphisms $\varphi:K\rightarrow L$, $\varphi':K'\rightarrow L$ such that $\varphi\circ f=\varphi' \circ g.$

Comment: Also, which book uses this definition for $\mathrm{Spec}\ A$? I have never seen it before. Usually this set is defined as the set of prime ideals of $A$ or, in some introductory courses, as the set of maximal ideals on $A$. In this case the definition is equivalent to the second one.

Comment: @nowheredense Our fields medalist Peter Scholze introduced Spec like that in his lecture notes for example (and then shows the other more usual description) - I checked them out of interest once and was also confused since i had never seen that before

Comment: @TMO That's interesting, thanks! (The notes are [here](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/ja/alggeoI/notes.pdf) in case someone is interested). 
Also, I wrongly said above that this is equivalent to the definition with maximal ideals but actually as the map is not assumed to be surjective it is equivalent to the definition with prime ideals.

Comment: @nowhere dense, so the author mentions that $f$ is equivalent to $f'$ means that there is a field $L$ and morphisms $\varphi:K\to L$ and $\varphi':K'\rightarrow L$ such that $\varphi\circ f=\varphi' \circ g$?

Comment: @mathbeginner yes, you can take that as the definition.

Comment: @nowhere dense， if we take the above definition, how to check that $f\sim g$ implies $g\sim f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will expand some of the comments since it seems like there is still some confusion. You are correct that for $f:A\to K$ and $g:A\to K'$ the relation $$ (f\sim' g)\iff (\exists\varphi:K\to K'\text{ such that }g = \phi\circ f) $$ is not symmetric, and therefore not an equivalence relation.

What the author means, is that $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $\sim'$. Thinking of an equivalence relation as a subset of the product, this means that $\sim$ is the smallest symmetric, transitive, and reflexive set of relations containing all the relations of $\sim'$.

This is what people generally mean when they define an equivalence relation by saying something like "... where these two things are identified if..."

You should check that the in this case, the equivalence relation generated by $\sim'$ can be stated explicitly as 
$$ (f\sim g) \iff ((\exists\varphi:K\to K'\text{ such that }g = \phi\circ f) \text{ or } (\exists\varphi:K'\to K\text{ such that }f = \phi\circ g)). $$